# How to add Time in Discord Bot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

How do you make a bot function so that the bot deletes the chat at 0 o'clock (the channel) how do you include times in the bot (Discord.py)

Please with example :)

thanks

I tried it with google but didnt work so please help

Comment: What did you try? What didn't work? In what way did it not work? Please include what you've tried in your question as that makes it easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the discord.ext.tasks extension! Just implement this example in your code and modify it so that it fits your variables!

```py
from discord.ext import tasks
from datetime import time #This at your import statements

purge_loop.start() # This cog_load function

@tasks.loop(time=time(hour=0, minute=0)) #this function in your cog
async def purge_loop(self):
   await channel.purge(limit=1000)
```